# Why is this behavour - my global hook works with a message loop but not with an empty loop?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'll preface this with saying that I am new to win32 programming.

I'm creating a global keyboard hook using a .dll, I have put in install and uninstall functions to handle the actual setting and removing of the keyboard hook.

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SECTION:.SHARED,RWS")
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
static HHOOK hk=NULL;
//static CMyFile *pLF;
#pragma data_seg()

HINSTANCE hins = NULL;

__declspec( dllexport ) LRESULT Install(){
    std::cout << "Installing" << std::endl;
    hk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,EventAnalysis::KeystrokeAnalysis::KeyboardCallback,hins,0);
    if(hk == NULL){
        std::cout << "Hook creation failed! - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


 __declspec(dllexport) BOOL CALLBACK UnInstall()
{
    std::cout << "UnInstalling" << std::endl;
    return UnhookWindowsHookEx(hk);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        hins = (HINSTANCE) hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

So now that I have my .dll, I created a simple executable that loads the library and installs the hooks:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto funHandle = LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Users\\tprodanov\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\HaveFun\\Release\\HaveFun.dll");
    if(funHandle == NULL){
        std::cout << "Library load failed! - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }

    auto Install = (LRESULT(*)()) GetProcAddress(funHandle, "?Install@@YAJXZ");
    if(Install == NULL){
        std::cout << "Procedure load failed! - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    Install();

    MSG Msg;

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }

    auto Uninstall = (BOOL(*)()) GetProcAddress(funHandle, "?UnInstall@@YGHXZ");
    if(Uninstall == NULL){
        std::cout << "Procedure load failed! - " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    Uninstall();
    return 0;
}
```

What I find curious is that the behavior of my program is as expected in its current state (and also if instead of a message loop I just pop out a MessageBox() that waits for the user to click OK), but it doesn't work if I use std::cin.get() or an empty while loop. Can someone please explain why this is the behavior?

Also as a followup question - the KeyboardCallback function just prints to the console "Key Pressed".

```
LRESULT CALLBACK EventAnalysis::KeystrokeAnalysis::KeyboardCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    std::cout << "Key pressed" << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL,nCode,wParam,lParam);
}
```

I expected that this will be printed only when I press keys when focused on the console window, but even if I type in notepad the "Key Pressed" messages show up in my executable that called the Install function of the .dll. I don't understand this, since as far as I understood the dynamic library is loaded independently in every process, so every process has its own copy of the KeyboardCallback function and it will try to print to the foreground window's console.

Comment: _"I expected that this will be printed only when I press keys when focused on the console window"_ Huh? Global keyboard hooks are well... global.

Comment: One very minor comment is that `UnInstall` is implemented using `__stdcall` but when you import it you declare the function to be `__cdecl`. You get away with that mismatch because there are no parameters. When you get rid of the unnecessary DLL you can just revert to use the default calling convention.

Comment: A WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook requires that you pump a message loop, the only way that Windows can make a call to your callback function.  It doesn't require a DLL.

Comment: @user2802841 I phrased it wrong, I meant that I expected the message to appear on the executable console only when I press a key in the console and not appear when I type in notepad, because notepad has no console. But, as David said, the callback is called in the context of the setter of the hook, so it all makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) makes it clear what is happening:

> This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it. The call is made by sending a message to the thread that installed the hook. Therefore, the thread that installed the hook must have a message loop.

The hook is installed by the call you made to `Install`. And so in the same thread that makes that call you need to run a message loop.

As for why showing a message box influences things, a message box operates by running a modal message loop. And that message loop will dispatch the hook messages.

And for the followup question, again the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985.aspx) has the answer:

> The system calls this function every time a new keyboard input event is about to be posted into a thread input queue.

When it says *posted into a thread input queue* it means *any thread input queue*.

Or in the remarks to the documentation of [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) look at the list of the various hook types, and their scope. The `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is listed as a global hook.

Note also that `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` is a low-level hook and so does not result in the DLL being injected into another process. In fact your code is overly complex. You simply do not need a DLL here at all. You can get it all going with a call to `SetWindowsHookEx` from your executable that passes a callback function in that same executable.

Here's a minimal sample program that demonstrates all this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Key pressed" << std::endl;
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Installing" << std::endl;
    HHOOK hk;
    hk = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardProc, NULL, 0);
    MSG Msg;
    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    std::cout << "UnInstalling" << std::endl;
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hk);
    return 0;
}
```